# Slice dataset on series by condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have dataset:

```
data = {'host': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
       'TS': ['1','2', '3', '7', '9','11','7','8','9','14','16', '18'], 
       'Predict' : ['None','None', '134','None','None', '127','None','None', '121','None','None', '124']}
```

I want to split dataset by not None values series and get time difference of this series.

I have function for time difference. And try to extract index for series, but don't know how it use

```
def timediffs(series):
    series['tdiff'] = series['ts'].diff().fillna(0.0)
    return series
```

```
predict_index = df.index.where(df['Predict'].notna()).to_series().bfill()
```

Finally, i want to get dataset like this:

```
new_data = {'host': ['A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B'],
       'TS': ['1','2', '3', '7', '9','11','7','8','9','14','16', '19'], 
       'Predict' : ['None','None', '134','None','None', '127','None','None', '121','None','None', '124'],
        'Time_diff' : ['0','1','1','0','2','2', '0','1','1','0','2','3',],
        'New_predict' : ['134','134','134','127','127','127','121','121','121','124','124','124',]
       }

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we replace `'None'` with `NaN`. Then we use `backfill (bfill)` to make our column, `New_predict` and finally we use `GroupBy.diff` to get the `Time_diff`:

```
df['New_predict'] = df.replace('None', np.NaN).loc[:, 'Predict'].bfill()
# df['TS'] = df['TS'].astype(int)
df['Time_diff'] = df.groupby('New_predict')['TS'].diff().fillna(0)

   host  TS Predict New_predict  Time_diff
0     A   1    None         134        0.0
1     A   2    None         134        1.0
2     A   3     134         134        1.0
3     A   7    None         127        0.0
4     A   9    None         127        2.0
5     A  11     127         127        2.0
6     B   7    None         121        0.0
7     B   8    None         121        1.0
8     B   9     121         121        1.0
9     B  14    None         124        0.0
10    B  16    None         124        2.0
11    B  18     124         124        2.0
```

Comment: if "Predict" value is not unique, how i can get two different sequences?
For example Predict(None, 25, None, 25) must be in different groups

Answer (score 1):

In your sample data first is necessary preprocessing data - convert `TS` to numeric and `Predict` `None` in strings to `NaN` or Nonetype:

```
df['TS'] = df['TS'].astype(int)
df['Predict'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Predict'], errors='coerce')
#if need replace strings None to NaN 
#df['Predict'] = df['Predict'].mask(df['Predict'] == 'None')
```

Then only back fill missing data in `Predict` column and for `Time_diff` use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with replace first values to `0`:

```
df['New_predict'] = df['Predict'].bfill()
df['Time_diff'] = df.groupby('New_predict')['TS'].diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   host  TS  Predict  New_predict  Time_diff
0     A   1      NaN        134.0          0
1     A   2      NaN        134.0          1
2     A   3    134.0        134.0          1
3     A   7      NaN        127.0          0
4     A   9      NaN        127.0          2
5     A  11    127.0        127.0          2
6     B   7      NaN        121.0          0
7     B   8      NaN        121.0          1
8     B   9    121.0        121.0          1
9     B  14      NaN        124.0          0
10    B  16      NaN        124.0          2
11    B  18    124.0        124.0          2
```